# Gradle: is it possible to configure java modules without subprojects?

Tags: java, gradle, java-9, java-module

in gradle it's easy to have multiple subprojects. each of subprojects can be a different java module. but having multiple subprojects clutters intellij's project view. With one project i can see all packages next to each other:

[image]

But with subprojects i have plenty of additional project folders, `src` folders, `java` folders etc:

[image]

also introducing multiple subprojects into a small application seems like an over-engineering (that's the same argument as against missing kotlin's package scope).

is there any pragmatic way to configure a package or set of packages as a java module with gradle?